# D3 zoomable sunburst not fully circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm just getting started with d3js and I'm trying to make a zoomable sunburst. I've copied a tutorial but because most of the data given there were very complex I tried to change the data into much simpler ones. Unfortunately after that , the outer svg becomes an incomplete circle. There's a line at the bottom of it. Not sure whether I have to change the data or the outerradius. Thanks in advance.

[image: Zoomable sunburst not fully circle]

```js
var flaredata = {
    "name": "Root",
    "children": [{
            "name": "A1",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "B1",
                    "size": 30
                },
                {
                    "name": "B2",
                    "size": 40
                },
                {
                    "name": "B3",
                    "size": 40
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "A2",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "B4",
                    "size": 40
                },
                {
                    "name": "B5",
                    "size": 30
                },
                {
                    "name": "B6",
                    "size": 10
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "A3",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "B7",
                    "size": 50
                },
                {
                    "name": "B8",
                    "size": 15
                }

            ]
        }
    ]
}

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("section").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .datum(flaredata) // this line is modified according to provided solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019572/d3-sunburst-doesnt-draw-with-inline-json
    // data() was replaced with datum() as suggested by Lars Kotthoff
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.size;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x)));
    })
    .endAngle(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx)));
    })
    .innerRadius(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, y(d.y));
    })
    .outerRadius(function(d) {
        return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy));
    });

// d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {

var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(partition.nodes) // removed "root" argument here
    .enter().append("g");

var path = g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name);
    })
    .on("click", click);

var text = g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return y(d.y);
    })
    .attr("dx", "6") // margin
    .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

function click(d) {
    // fade out all text elements
    text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);

    path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
        .each("end", function(e, i) {
            // check if the animated element's data e lies within the visible angle span given in d
            if (e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) {
                // get a selection of the associated text element
                var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
                // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
                arcText.transition().duration(750)
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .attr("transform", function() {
                        return "rotate(" + computeTextRotation(e) + ")"
                    })
                    .attr("x", function(d) {
                        return y(d.y);
                    });
            }
        });
}
// });

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Interpolate the scales!
function arcTween(d) {
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
        yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
        yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
    return function(d, i) {
        return i ?
            function(t) {
                return arc(d);
            } :
            function(t) {
                x.domain(xd(t));
                y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
                return arc(d);
            };
    };
}

function computeTextRotation(d) {
    return (x(d.x + d.dx / 2) - Math.PI / 2) / Math.PI * 180;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The circle is drawn completely. The problem might be that your SVG is not big enough to display all of it with the given y-translation of 10.

One of the most easy way might be to change this line of code:

radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 5; // <-- -5 is just a suggestion.

If you want to display it in the biggest size possible without any borders you can change the following line of code instead which is "the main source" of your problem:

```
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")"); // + 10 as y translation makes the element appear with a top distance of 260 in this case.
```

If you remove the +10 it should perfectly fit inside the SVG.